# Validate Request body in spring using @Valid

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am want to validate a JSON object, for length of an attribute. I am using @Size annotation to specify maximum length as shown below.

```
@JsonRootName("question")
public class QuestionJson {
    @JsonProperty(value = "id", required = false)
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "text", required = true)
    private String label;
    @JsonProperty(value = "answers", required = true)
    private List<AnswerJson> answers;

}

@JsonRootName("answer")
public class AnswerJson {
@JsonProperty(value = "id", required = false)
private Long id;
@JsonProperty(value = "type", required = true)
private String type;

@JsonProperty(value = "label", required = true)
@Size(message = "size should not be long", max = 10)
private String label;
}
```

My request mapping in controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/answer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public AnswerJson createQuestion(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) final String authorizationHeader, @Valid @RequestBody final QuestionJson questionJson) {
    // some code here....
    return answer;

}
```

UPDATE: Validation works on the outer elements eg. `text` in my case but fails on the nested list.

Comment: How does your json request look like?

Comment: {"id":15,"text":"what are your favourite fruits?","answers":[{"id":35,"type":"label","label":"apples"},{"id":36,"type":"label","label":"trewtwertertfsaf"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Every time we use `@Valid` annotation we also include a `BindingResult` instance as a method parameter, it contains the `@Valid` marked parameter errors if any:

```
public final @ResponseBody String theMethod(
            final @Valid ValidableObjectImpl validableObject,
            BindingResult result) {

    try {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            for (FieldError error : result.getFieldErrors()){
                // do something
            }
            // return error
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `BindingResult` is not required by default. If it's not present then Spring will throw `MethodArgumentNotValidException` on validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. We need add `@Valid` annotation to the before the declaration of the nested object. eg

```
@JsonRootName("question")
public class QuestionJson {
    @JsonProperty(value = "id", required = false)
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "text", required = true)
    private String label;
    @JsonProperty(value = "answers", required = true)
    @Valid
    private List<AnswerJson> answers;

}
```